# can't create frame from exercises, problem with points[]

Tags: r

I don't know if my Professor made a mistake, or if it's a problem with my computer, but I can't create a data frame from code he posted.

He is using something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(nrow=0,ncol=4)
for (i in 1:10) {
   for (j in 1:10) {
      if(i>j) { 
         df[10*(i-1)+j,1] <- points[i,1]
         df[10*(i-1)+j,2] <- points[i,2]
         df[10*(i-1)+j,3] <- points[j,1]
         df[10*(i-1)+j,4] <- points[j,2] 
      } 
    } 
} 
df <- df[complete.cases(df),]
```

and I get the error:

> Error in points[i, 1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Am i missing something?

Comment: The error suggests `points` might be a function rather than an array/dataframe, in which case you should be using `(...)` not `[...]`

Comment: It looks like this code is assuming that you have already created a data frame called `points` in your workspace, e.g. by reading data from a file.

Comment: I don't think the comment and answer here suggesting `points()` will help the OP at all: the result of `points()` is always `NULL` ...

Comment: Yeee the point is that i don't think its function, we haven't made something like this before, and even if the whole sentence of exercise is "create dataframe, which will contain those pairs of points:" and after this is whole code that i putted, nothing else. The best is that next 4 exercises are about this dataframe.